# Share database with XAMPP on Mac and PC

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm using XAMPP and Bitbucket to keep all of my computers up to date with my website files and databases.

I have a PC desktop and a PC laptop that work fine together when it comes to updating databases between each other.

I now have a Mac laptop and for some reason, when I try to update my database to the one the PCs are using, it doesn't work. MySQL won't start when I tell it to using XAMPP.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Bagwell!

I used to use Xampp as well on my PC, however, recently I switched to "Vagrant".

Vagrant uses Oracles free Virtual Box software to create a Virtual Machine on your computer.  Once set up, you can access your server on your local network via Mac or PC.

It's quite easy to setup, as there is a great website called www.puphet.com where you can create a configuration file for your VM.

Anyhow, I found a great video online which explains how to setup Vagrant -
https://jtreminio.com/2013/05/introduction_to_vagrant_puppet_and_introducing_puphpet_a_simple_to_use_vagrant_puppet_gui_configurator/

Once you choose vagrant, I doubt you will ever use Xampp again.

Hope this helps!